# Mercurial clone is missing files (actually, just gets into different  branch)

Tags: mercurial

I have a seemingly normal mercurial repo, but doing a local clone of it leaves out bunches of files…

```
bash-3.2$ hg verify
repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
486 files, 23 changesets, 568 total revisions

bash-3.2$ hg clone . /tmp/clone
updating to branch default
resolving manifests
getting .hgignore
getting data/Agricultural Marketing Service - Agricultural Marketing Service - Home.html
getting data/SAMPLE_BIZ_FARMERS_MARKETS.XLS
...
130 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
bash-3.2$
```

[update: the problem was that the original repository was in branch foo; and the clone gets created with the default branch current, which confused me]

Comment: what's the output of `hg verify` in the newly cloned repo ?

Comment: are there any branches on the source repo ? it could explain your "problem".

Comment: since you figured this out you should probably delete it or rework it into a question that's more generally useful.

Comment: Wouldn't let me delete it so I edited it a bit.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. It's always the silly issues that get you.

Answer (score 3):

Please show `hg summary` in both the original and the clone.  It's possible you're updated to different revisions in each repository.  Cloning a repository brings across the changesets, but doesn't update to the same revision as the source.

Also please show `hg status` for a file that's in the original but not in the clone.

Comment: Oh never mind, I'm an idiot. The original repository was in a named branch (which I had forgotten about), and the clone was reverting to default branch, which is why they looked different.  Anyway, thanks for helping me clear up my confusion.

Comment: No prob.  You can clone to a specific branch using '#branch' at the end of the URL if it helps in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There might be deleted files-- those would be in the repository, but not in the working directory.  If I'm not mistaken, "N files updated" refers to the working directory in Mercurial.

Comment: No, they aren't deleted, they are right there in the original repository and seemingly perfectly normal.